# How would I finish this script that multiply user input by 100 and then outputs it to the console when in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is create a script that can take any number that the user inputs into a field and multiplies it by 100 and outputs it to the console when the button is pressed. I have it partially completed but I am unfamiliar with console.log and a novice with javascript overall. 
I've been reading around but I can't seem to figure out something that seems like it should be so simple. It is only 1 field + 1 button.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Java Help</h1>
        <input id="Variables"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="getInput()"/>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my Javascript is here:

```
/**
* Created by Jabrian on 1/24/2015.
*/
function getInput(){

var userInput= document.getElementByID("Variables").value;

console.log("100" * userInput);
```

Comment: well to start you're missing the ending semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. See below:

```js
function getInput() {
  var userInput= document.getElementById("Variables").value;
  var answer = 100 * parseFloat(userInput);
  console.log(answer);
  alert(answer);
}
```

```html
<input id="Variables" value="10"/>
<input type="button" value="Multiply" onclick="getInput()"/>
```

Comment: @rosscowar It's true. But if you're going to do that you should probably also use `100 * parseFloat(userInput)` since you want to avoid the auto coercion caused by the `*` operator